# Why I get infinite loop when do regex matching?

Tags: regex, perl

When I use next program to parse input file:

```
my $content =  "@{[ <> ]}";
@cts =  $content =~ m/^CREATE TABLE .*? \(\n.*?\);$/gsm;
print @cts;
```

All works fine, but this (second) do not end:

```
my $content =  "@{[ <> ]}";
@cts =  "@{[ <> ]}" =~ m/^CREATE TABLE .*? \(\n.*?\);$/gsm;
print @cts;
```

**UPD**
*perlop*:

> The null filehandle <> is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk, and any other Unix filter program that takes a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of them. Input from <> comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line

There is **UNEXPECTED** no output for second case when I run script as:

```
./prepare_migration.pl < psql.schema3
```

There is **UNEXPECTED** infinite loop (waiting input from STDIN) for second case when I run script as:

```
./prepare_migration.pl psql.schema3
```

But for first case both variants to run program works fine and produce same output. Also there is no any waiting for STDIN.

Comment: `my $content =  "@{[ <> ]}"` adds spaces at the start of every line after the first. To read a whole file into a scalar variable, write `my $content = do{ local $/; <>; }`

Comment: It's also a bad idea to blindly add `/ms` to every regex pattern that you write. In this case the `/m` makes no difference as you have no `^` or `$` in your pattern, but the `/s` makes `.*?` able to span multiple lines, which could significantly slow down your program and generate incorrect results

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. I can't reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: done. Thank you. Examples were not full. Doing Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example I have found error. I update examples...

Comment: @Borodin: thank you for comments. The regex was not finished yet. I have fix that to be clear despite on that is not belongs to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems most likely that you supplied the input file as an argument for the first program, but you didn't when running the second program. Otherwise there is no substantial difference.

Comment: Exactly. The program is presumably waiting for input from the console rather than being in an "infinite loop"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. When I do "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example" I have found error. I forget to comment line

```
my $content =  "@{[ <> ]}"; # <<---  I SHOULD COMMENT THIS
@cts =  "@{[ <> ]}" =~ m/CREATE TABLE .*? \(\n.*?\);\n/gsm;
print @cts;
```

So when I do `./prepare_migration.pl < psql.schema3` the @ARGV filehandle is empty and there is nothing to read. So @cts empty.

when I do `./prepare_migration.pl psql.schema3` the @ARGV filehandle is 'psql.schema3'. Content is read to $content. And for second **readline** <> operator it is binded to STDIN. So I get "infinite loop"